# LaTex vs ShareLateX

Tags: sharelatex

This may be a touchy question but I am considering using ShareLaTeX for a book I am working on.  I am beginner in LaTeX and ShareLaTeX seems very easy to use and user-friendly.  However, since I eventually plan to publish this book I am concerned about security at internet sites like ShareLaTeX.  I am not going use "group" (paid for more than 2) feature if I decide to go with ShareLaTex.  My second question concerns portability.  Can I go back and forth between my own computer (where I have installed TeXshop) and ShareLaTex or are there some issues or concerns I should worry about?  Any thoughts and/or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Portability should not be a problem. As far as I know sharelatex uses a fairly recent version of texlive - the only point which might be a problem is, if you decide to use special fonts which are only installed on sharelatex and not on your own computer or vice versa.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Note that TeXshop is just a front-end to a TeX distribution. Which TeX distribution do you use on your own computer? MacTeX, right?